# Adding jQuery to WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I was just wondering if anyone could help me out with this query.

In my WordPress theme, in the functions.php file I was adding in jQuery like so...

```
wp_register_script(‘jquery’, ‘http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
```

I've been doing this for a while however today this stopped working, and to fix the issue I had to change it to the following, note the 1.8.3 version number.

```
wp_register_script(‘jquery’, ‘http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
```

Could anyone enlighten me to why this happened and could this potentially happen again, If so, is there anything I can do to stop it happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `jquery/1/` gives you the latest release of jquery - so it may be that the jquery scripts you have running are using some calls which have been deprecated in the latest release of jquery?

Comment: you can read this for reference about why it is bad to link the first way you did it. http://www.impressivewebs.com/linking-to-jquery/

Comment: Download the latest version of jQuery and test whether your script work well with that version. I guess that there is some lines in your code not compatible with jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it stopped working today is that JQuery 1.9 was just released yesterday and this deprecated a few functions that you might have been using. The `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js` will always link to the latest code point released, so you unknowingly switched from the previous release to 1.9 and some of your functions stopped working. By using `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` you will always be using the same version of jquery, even when jquery 2.0 is released in the upcoming weeks(or days or months) and your code will be more stable. The link I provided in the comment of your question goes more in depth about why it is bad to use the latest release automatically. http://www.impressivewebs.com/linking-to-jquery/.

Here is a link to the release notes for 1.9 that explains the changes you implemented by accident - http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9

And here is jquery's blog post about 1.9 and 2.0 from January 15th - http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

Comment: Thanks for the help very useful links too!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't register your own copy of jQuery, or even one from a CDN. You need to do such things with great care or you will **break things** and then need to get help... like now!

If you want to use a CDN-hosted copy of jQuery, also jQuery-ui and a couple of other Google-hosted scripts, please just use the plugin [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/). It will use the same version as your copy of WordPress, so you will avoid using newer, *or older*, versions.